# Comparing temporal types using Memgraph MAGE

Tags: memgraphdb

I have a Memgraph 2.0.0 running as Memgraph MAGE inside Docker. I have a query and I want to sort the results using properties with temporal types.

My query is:

```
CREATE({a: DATE('2023-01-15')}), ({a: DATE('2023-01-05')}), ({a: DATE('2023-02-01')})

MATCH (n) RETURN n.a ORDER BY n.a
```

This is the error that I can see in my log: `[2023-02-14 10:05:17.354] [memgraph_log] [critical] Unhandled comparison for types`

Comment: It would be helpful to include an example of the query that is failing in the question.

Comment: I've just edited the question and I've added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to upgrade Memgraph to 2.1.0. Be on the lookout for breaking changes. This bug was fixed in [Memgraph 2.1](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/changelog#v210---nov-22-2021).